# Вывести Unicode-значения каждого символа строки через пробел

Tags: javascript, функции, unicode

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать функцию, которая принимает строку на вход и возвращает другую строку, состоящую из Unicode-значений символов входной строки, разделенных пробелами.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function asUTF8Codes(str) {
    return (Array.prototype.map.call(str, function(char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0);
    })).join(" ");
}

console.log(asUTF8Codes("string"));
```

```js
function asUTF8Codes(str) {
    let output = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        output += str.charCodeAt(i) + " ";
    }
    return output.trim();
}

console.log(asUTF8Codes("string"));
```

```js
function asUTF8Codes(str) {
    let output = "",
        length = str.length,
        i = 0;

    while (i < length) {
        output += (i === length - 1) ? str.charCodeAt(i) : str.charCodeAt(i) + " ";

        i++;
    }

    return output;
}

console.log(asUTF8Codes("string"));
```

В общем, вариантов тьма.

Кстати, учитывайте, что и сам пробел в строке будет считаться отдельным символом. Если такое поведение нежелательно, то можно, например, сразу профильтровать строку, избавившись от всех пробельных символов.

Сделать это тоже можно разными способами. Но в вопросе про это ничего не сказано, поэтому я и не реализовал.